# proper use for Azure DevOps token in Backstage repo publish template action step (publish:azure)?

Tags: azure-devops, backstage

I am working with Backstage and am able to create a template that publishes a repo to a known Azure DevOps organization using a PAT I have generated - but **I am only able to do so with a hard-coded PAT added to my example template.yaml - obviously this is undesirable**.

I have tried accessing the value stored as an environment variable like so:

`PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN=some_token_here yarn dev`

and attempted to access the interpolated value within the template from having set it the app config, something along the lines of

```
    - id: publish
      name: Publish
      action: publish:azure
      input:
        allowedHosts: ['dev.azure.com']
        description: This is ${{ parameters.name }}
        repoUrl: ${{ parameters.repoUrl }}
        # does not work
        token: ${{ config.azureDevOps.token }} or other versions based on docs
        # -vs-
        # works
        token: some-actual-hardcoded-value
```

It returns a 401 for pushing to the repo... but only after successfully creating an empty repo.

I am using an Azure AD backed organization, and the user in question who generated the PAT (me) has full access.

I noticed there is reference to using requestUserCredentials to instead retrieve a token on behalf of the authenticated user to the backstage instance (see here: https://backstage.io/docs/features/software-templates/writing-templates), but at this juncture I don't have auth set up yet.

I have tried scouring the docs and several raised issues regarding the interpolation syntax being confusing, so I might just be missing the obvious, but I can't actually find a reference to accessing a value like this from within a template in the way I am trying.

Is this possible?
Should I be doing something different? (like setting up AzDo as my auth provider for the instance in app-config?)

Thanks!

Comment: It’s more of a backstage problem, check if can find useful info from here: https://backstage.io/docs/reference/plugin-azure-devops/